# How to check previous character in a string?

Tags: string

string1 = 'AAABBBBCDDBBECE'

empty_lst = []

result = ''

for i in string1:

if string1[i] != string1[i+1]:

result += string1[i]

print(result)
#help me out from here

I am a beginner and this is part of a question from my assignment. The goal is to create a new string with all the consecutive duplicates removed from a given string.

Note - Only consecutive letters are removed not all duplicate occurences of a letter.  From the 3 consecutive "A"s, 2 are removed and we have 'A' only. Then from the 4 consecutive 'B's, 3 are removed and only one is added to the new string giving us "AB". Since we have only one 'C' next, it is added making the resulting string "ABC" now and so on.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the easiest way to do this would be to use a regex replacement:

```py
import re

string1 = "AAABBBBCDDBBECE"
output = re.sub(r'(\w)\1+', r'\1', string1)
print(output)  # ABCDBECE
```